# Convergence in distribution and ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence

Assuming we have an ODE $y'_n(x) = f_n(x) y_n(x)$
 with $f_n$ be Gauß-densities with mean value 0 and variance $\frac{1}{n}$, then we have that they converge in distribution to a delta peak $δ(x)$. Now, assume that we solved the ODE $y′_n(x)=f_n(x)y_n(x)$ for every n with $y(−∞)=y_0$ specified. In what sense does the solution yn(x) convergence to y(x), where y(x) solves $y′(x)=δ(x)y(x)$?

I want to understand this convergence without solving the ODE $y′_n(x)=f_n(x)y_n(x)$ explicitely(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$ d\log y_n= f_n dx $$

which  tells you that the measures $d\log y_n$ converge weakly to $\delta$.    For more precise statements I refer you to Section 1 of  [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/cobord-degen.pdf) where I and my collaborator study what happens to  operators such as $\frac{d}{dx}-f_n(x)$    as $n\to\infty$.     There we are mostly interested  on $x$ restricted to a compact interval and $y_n$ constrained  to satisfy some boundary conditions. The upshot is that the operators converge  in the sense that their graphs have a limit as $n\to\infty$ and in many case we  can give a precise  description of this limit.

Let me give you a taste. From the   fact that $d\log y_n\to \delta$ we deduce that for any $r>0$ we have

$$\log y_n(r)-\log y_n(-r)=\int_{[-r,r]} \delta (x) dx=1. $$

This implies that

$$ y_n(r)/y_n(-r)\to e. $$

Suppose that $y_n(-r)\to c$ Using the results in the above paper you can conclude that $y_n$ converges in $L^2(-r,r)$ to

$$y_\infty(x)=\begin{cases}
c, & x<0 \\
ec, & x>0.
\end{cases} $$

Comment: There's a typo in what I wrote. I meant $d\log y_n \to \delta$

Comment: No I have not seen anything like that.